# How can I save an array object to file at run-time by chrome debug tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filesystems, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to extract an array object at run-time. For example:

```
var myarr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

How can I save `myarr` at location `/home/username/myarr.txt` in Chrome DevTools?

Comment: Chrome doesn't allow writing to an arbitrary path in the real file system. Chrome extensions may use chrome.downloads API to save the files to paths inside the downloads directory and that's about all.

Answer (score 15):

You can't download to a specific location, however you can download this file to your Chrome downloads path (where all your files are download in to).
Try this (it is working for me):

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var a = document.createElement('a');
var file = new Blob([ arr.toString() ], { type: 'text/plain' });

a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.download = 'bla';
a.click();
```

It should download a file named 'bla' containing the array values.

Comment: this is a good answer, definitely deserve to be marked as correct ans.

Comment: This was awesome 

Comment: I didn't make it work at the beginning. I typed the code in the console, but errors occurred. Later I tried to copy the code above into the source window, where I set up a breakpoint, then continued to run the modified code, and it worked eventually. I leave this comment for those searching for a solution but can't make it.